# Any way to swithc default rout to vpn when connecting?

Tags: networking, gnome, networkmanager, vpn

I'm using gnome NetworkManager and connectiong via openconnect to a vpn server, but my default rout is not changing when i'm connected and all traffic goes around vpn.
Can i somehow make NetworkManager switch the default route when i'm turning vpn on and switch it back when turning vpn off ?

Answer (score 0):

I need to do this with a Palo Alto vpn client as well. I don't use Network Manager but you can easily see your routes at the command line and alter them there if nothing else works for you.

When I'm associated with a wi-fi Access Point, my route looks like the one below (with the AP being my default gateway). A gateway/router is specified as having a `0.0.0.0` Destination and `UG` (Up,Gateway) under the `flags` column in the `route` output:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.12.110.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan1
10.9.8.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
172.12.110.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.128.0   U     9      0        0 wlan1
```

After connecting to my VPN, the AP is *still* the default gateway, since it is the first entry in the routing table having `UG` flags:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.12.110.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan1
0.0.0.0         10.115.186.212  0.0.0.0         UG    10     0        0 gpd0
10.9.8.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
140.110.254.254 10.115.186.212  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 gpd0
207.15.254.227  172.12.110.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan1
207.15.254.254  10.115.186.212  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 gpd0
172.12.110.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.128.0   U     9      0        0 wlan1
```

In order to actually route my traffic over the VPN link, I need to delete the `172.12.110.1` gateway using `sudo` and the `route` command:
`sudo route del default`

Now my default gateway is set to my VPN router/link which is `10.115.186.212`.

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.115.186.212  0.0.0.0         UG    10     0        0 gpd0
10.9.8.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
140.110.254.254 10.115.186.212  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 gpd0
207.15.254.227  172.12.110.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan1
207.15.254.254  10.115.186.212  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 gpd0
172.12.110.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.128.0   U     9      0        0 wlan1
```

I'm pretty sure this can all be accomplished automatically using `/etc/network/interfaces` with the `post-up` hooks or something, but I just never bothered to look into it.

You can verify your egress (before and after the route edit) by connecting your browser to [Google with an IP query](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20my%20ip)